# Why Model is not returning the data via slug except id?

Tags: laravel, slug, laravel-6

I have a problem with laravel views when I tried to get data in view via slug not through the id.
Here is my route:

```
Route::get('post/{post}','PostController@post')->name('post');
```

This is postController function:

```
public function post(post $post)
{
    return view('user.post',compact('post'));
}
```

This is model function:

```
public function grtRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Its getting error 404 but when do some changes in Route:

```
Route::get('post/{slug}','PostController@post')->name('post');
```

Its returns the view but not the data I want from the table.

Comment: model function is misspelled

Answer (score 3):

#### A brief introduction to Laravel's [implicit-binding](http://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#implicit-binding)

If `/{post}` contains an id and your table has id column then Laravel will take care of it.

If you would like model binding to use a database column other than id when retrieving a given model class, you may override the getRouteKeyName method on the Eloquent model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';  // db column name
}
```

In the above question, you need to correct the method name `grtRouteKeyName` to  `getRouteKeyName` spelling, hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `getRouteKeyName()`

Answer (score 1):

Your function name is incorrect, so change it to this:

```
public function getRouteKeyName() {
    return 'slug';  // table column name.
}
```